# Using powershell and WPF how to display a selected directory path in a list box

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell

I found this Powershell function code block to choose a folder. Then, I added two variables (sourcePath, source) to reference to a XAML file. When, user presses "OK", I need the selected folder path to be shown in a different list box,"$sourcePath". I tried calling the list box as " $sourcePath.Write($objForm.SelectedPath)" after the "Return $objForm.SelectedPath". I'm doing something wrong, but don't know how to fix it. Thank you.

```
$XAML = @'
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Choose Folder" Height="350" Width="500">
<StackPanel>      
<Button x:Name="choose" Content="choose" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
Margin="42,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" />
<ListBox x:Name="sourcePath" HorizontalAlignment="left" Height="45" 
Margin="42,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"/> 
</StackPanel>
</Window>
'@

$sourcePath=$win.Find("sourcePath")
$source=$win.Find("source")
$source.Add_click({Select-FolderDialog})
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |        
Out-Null
Function Select-FolderDialog 
{param([string]$Description="Select Folder",[string]$RootFolder="Desktop")   
 $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
 $objForm.Rootfolder = $RootFolder
 $objForm.Description = $Description
 $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
    If ($Show -eq "OK")
    {
     Return $objForm.SelectedPath
     $sourcePath.Write($objForm.SelectedPath)
    }
    Else
    {
      Write-Error "Operation cancelled by user."
    }
    $b = Select-FolderDialog
}
```

Comment: Please fix sample. You reference objects that are never defined

Comment: Thank You, Frode F, PeterXX.  I added the reference objects as requested.  PeterXX posted the solution what I was looking for. Thank you both. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There were only a few minor things wrong like using "write" for putting something into a ListBox.

And of course, like Frode F. pointed out, ommit the return - there is no need for a return statement inside a function except for leaving the function before it ends.

Here is a slightly modified version of your script code that display a window with a listbox and button and puts the selected path into that listbox.

```
$XAML = @'

<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Folder-Browser"
  Height="500"
  Width="600"
>
 <StackPanel>
  <ListBox x:Name="sourcePath" Height="300" Width="320" Margin="10"/>
  <Button x:Name="choose" Content="Choose Folder" Width="120" Height="40" Margin="10"/>
 </StackPanel>
</Window>
'@

$Win = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($XAML)
$sourcePath = $Win.FindName("sourcePath")
$button = $Win.FindName("choose")
$button.Add_Click({Select-FolderDialog})

Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.forms

function Select-FolderDialog 
{
  param([String]$Description="Select Folder", 
        [String]$RootFolder="Desktop")   

  $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
  $objForm.Rootfolder = $RootFolder
  $objForm.Description = $Description
  $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
  if ($Show -eq "OK")
  {
     $SourcePath.Items.Add($objForm.SelectedPath)
  }
}

$Win.ShowDialog()
```

If the Script runs with PowerShell 4.0 and above I recommend the parse method which returns the Window object right away:

```
$Win = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($Xaml)
```

Comment: Thank you, PeterXX. You posted what I was looking for. Appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Return $objForm.SelectedPath`. It returns the value to the console and ends the function which means that `$sourcePath.Write($objForm.SelectedPath)` is never executed.

> The Return keyword exits a function, script, or script block

Source: [about_Return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return)